# python Output specific characters only if they are after a number

Tags: regex, python-3.x

```
a = 'adk7.86311kgskg'
r = "".join(re.sub('[^0-9*kg.]', "", a.strip().replace(' ', '')))

print(r)
#'k7.86311kgkg'
```

The results I want are as follows.

```
'7.86311kg'
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
print(re.findall(r'[\d.]+kg', 'adk7.86311kgskg')[0])
```

This outputs:

```
7.86311kg
```

Comment: oh thanks but The decimal point must also be output. '7.86311kg'

Comment: oh thanks but The decimal point must also be output. '7.86311kg'

Comment: My bad. I've updated my answer with the decimal point included.

Comment: Beware that if there are digits after your number (as in `'adk8.63a11kgskg'`), those digits will be matched: `'11kg'`.